# error : incompatible types while using ANT Script

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm getting Below error while compile java code using ant script.

```
[javac] D:\MySapce\Proj001\src\com\\process\ReportsProcess.java:2081: error: incompatible types
[javac]         Integer i = Collections.max(arrayList);
[javac]                                    ^
[javac]   required: Integer
[javac]   found:    Object
```

How can i resolve the problem?

Error Code Part:

```
if(series1!=null && series1.getData().size()>0 ){

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList (Arrays.asList( series1.getData().values().toArray()));

    Integer i = Collections.max(arrayList);
    series1MaxValue = i;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `arrayList`?

Comment: found as Object type.. Need `List<Integer>`..

Comment: @Satya `Collections.max` doesn't require `Integer`. The error message refers to the return type, not the parameter.

Comment: @Satya: The return type is `T`, which means if the OP is going to assign to an `Integer` variable, it'll need to be a `Collection<Integer>` argument, effectively.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Ant, really - I'd expect the same behaviour when compiling from the command-line or in an IDE.

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit the question and add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a raw-typed `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(...);
```

The compiler can't infer what the type of these elements are; you can actually put anything into the list as well as `Integer`s.

Add the type of the elements which will be put into the list:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(...);
```

Also, refer to Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 23 ("Don’t use raw types in new code") for a detailed explanation of why you should not use raw types.

Comment: after changed the ArrayList as Integer, i can't pass the above mentioned value its showing error.